# can't connect to Selenium server from vagrant machine

Tags: django, selenium, vagrant

i built my first web project on a vagrant machine. I would like to run some browser tests with selenium. i have the tests (and rest of project) on virtual machine.

it appears that I can use selenium server standalone to connect to my local machine and run the browsers on the local machine.

On the local machine, I run the following: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar`

I get a bunch of successful code including: `osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@709a8be8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}`

Presumably, that is where i can connect from my virtual machine.

I then have a small python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
   command_executor='http://0.0.0.0:4444',
   desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

I get the following error: `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>`

I can't find much more detail on this process than these steps. If someone could help with this problem, I'd be grateful.

Comment: `http://0.0.0.0:4444` should replace to your loal machin IP address, rathan 0.0.0.0  And you need to make sure the virtual machine can access your local machine , like ping <local machine IP address> from virtual machine

Comment: how do i find my local machine IP address?

Comment: For windows, execute ipconfig in cmd window, for linux, execute ifconfig on local machine, or google search guide

Comment: IMO, you need to update the question if you are using `selenium server` (as per question heading) or `selenium grid - hub/node config` (as per code block)

Comment: wasn't even aware of the distinction. where does the code block reference "selenium grid"?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```